# How can I make a maintainable PhoneGap page with lots of images?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I'm making a simple web app with [PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) to display lots of images. How can I make this page maintainable with images that might get added or removed?

It appears from other questions that I can't use jQuery to dynamically load the images from a directory into the page, so it looks like I'll have to statically insert the images as html (or a JS list that creates an image element for each). Is there a better way to do this?

It should be noted that this page is standalone with no server behind it, so I can't use php or ASP.NET to load the images into the page dynamically.

Comment: What's the question exactly? Where do the pictures reside, and why can't you do it statically?

Comment: @Jivings the question is how can I make this page manageable? I have a few hundred images (thumbnails that link to full images), and these might get removed or added to frequently. It's very unmanagable to statically code links to hundreds of images that might change weekly.

Comment: It looks like the real solution to this is; use a web server.

Comment: @Jivings - this app is to be stored on smartphones and tablets in a PhoneGap application shell. There are *always* other ways to solve problems, but not all of them fit every situation.

Comment: So it's to display photos that are on the device?

Comment: Edited my answer now that I know it's phonegap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No back end makes it slightly more difficult but I'll offer a suggestion.

I suggest creating a text file. This file consists of the list of filenames for your images.
When the page is loaded, request this list using AJAX. Then loop through each line of this file and load each image into the page using JavaScript and the filename.

If you want anything more maintainable than that then you're looking at a PHP backed database.

EDIT:

If you'd have said phonegap then I'd have said it's totally possible.
First use a [DirectoryReader](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader). With each entry in the returned list you can create a [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileEntry). You should be then able to create an image to display in the page with the FileEntry, but I have no knowledge of this specific function.

Comment: Hahah wow, I don't know why I didn't mention it before. Thanks. that should work.

Comment: It appears that doing this gives me access to the cache (LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY) and the sdcard (LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT) but I can't seem to get access to a directory within my app package (a relative directory in the WWW folder). Any advice?